# Is there a way to factor $A\cos(x)+B\cos(y)$?

Tags: trigonometry

A quite basic question.
A lot of trigonometric formula are available, but I don't find anything factoring out this :
$$A \, \cos(x) + B \, \cos(y)$$

It's for instance well known that   :
$$A \, \cos(x) + B \, \sin(x) = C \, \sin(x+\theta)$$
where $C=\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$ and $\sin(\theta) = \frac{A}{C}$ and $\cos(\theta) = \frac{B}{C}$,
but is there something similar for $A \, \cos(x)+B \, \cos(y)$ ?
Thank you if you have an answer.

Comment: I think you meant to write $B\sin(x)$ in your second equation.

Comment: Just express $\cos$ as a $\sin$ with a phase shift!

Comment: The quoted well-known formula is incorrect if $y\ne x$, so I assume that you meant $A\cos x+B\sin x$ on the left-hand side. However, the question being asked becomes trivial when $y=x$, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @JacobA That just "shifts" the problem to combining phase-shifted functions. :-)

Comment: Take $$x\longmapsto x,~~y\longmapsto \frac{3\pi}{2}-y$$

Comment: @John Wayland Bales and Greg Martin : Sorry for the typo. It is indeed $A \, \cos(x) + B \, \sin(x)$ in my example (second equation).

Comment: I doubt there is such a formula.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews : you must be right, but just in case...

Comment: There's no way to reduce the expression to a function of one variable (unless $A = 0$ or $B = 0$), if that's what you have in mind by "factorization".

Comment: I thank everyone for his help. So it seems that there is no way to simplify such an expression.